DocumentDB change streams guaranteed delivery?
I read that DocumentDB and MongoDB have a time-ordered sequence of change events and that DocumentDB can store events for 3 hours (extended up to 7 days). Talking about MongoDB, since their change streams depend on the replica set oplog, the client requesting the event is not guaranteed to receive it. On the other hand, to enable change streams on DocumentDB, you need to provide a primary connection, not only that, but DocumentDB does not support oplogs like MongoDB... Is that an indication that DocumentDB guarantees pulled events through Change Streams?
